# Concurrent Authentication Token Renewal in Haskell

Tags: authentication, haskell, concurrency, stm

I am developing a web service in Haskell.
It makes requests to other web services, some of which require authentication.
Currently, I have something like this:

```hs
renewToken :: Credentials -> IORef Token -> IO Token
renewToken credentials tokenRef = do
    token <- readIORef tokenRef
    time <- getCurrentTime
    if time < expiration token then pure token else do
        newToken <- request "http://example.com/login" credentials
        writeIORef tokenRef newToken
        pure newToken
```

The `renewToken` function can then be used before requests which require authentication:

```hs
do
    token <- renewToken credentials tokenRef
    request "http://example.com/data" token
```

This setup does not handle concurrency very well.
Concurrent uses of `renewToken` may renew the token multiple times and overwrite each other's results.

How can I implement the token renewal process in a way that is safe and efficient in a concurrent setting?

I have heard that STM is a great way of doing concurrency in Haskell, so I wanted to use that.
However, I do not understand how to use it here, since the token renewal process performs IO.
As far as I understood, there is no sensible way to do IO in an STM transaction, since it may retry.
I have often heard STM proposed as a higher-level alternative to `MVar`s, but I do not understand how this would work if there is IO.

I could use `withMVar` to ensure that only one thread can enter the token renewal process at a time.
However, this would needlessly serialize all the read-only accesses to the token when it has not expired yet.
I am afraid that this might lead to increased latency when there are many concurrent requests.
Moreover, `MVar` seems like a very low-level primitive that does not have the composability of something like STM.
Am I really supposed to use `MVar` directly in a situation like this?

Finally, I considered the solution of having a separate thread that is responsible for token renewal.
However, this again serializes all accesses to the token.
On top of that, it creates significant complexity and potential overhead via communication between threads.

Comment: "cached-io" might be useful for this use-case https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cached-io Although, if I understand the docs correctly, it returns the stale value if it's requested in the middle of a refresh, which isn't what we want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this would needlessly serialize all the read-only accesses to the token

You would serialize checking whether the token is expired or not, but
you don't need to serialize the network requests that are made using
the token.  The cost is tiny compared to the network request itself.

We can do this in STM without needing to put any IO inside the
transactions.  We use a small state machine with a "pending" state so
that a thread can see when another thread is already renewing the
token.  So a TVar with something like this in it.

```
data TokenState = None | Pending | Got Token
```

(If you always get a token at startup maybe you can do without the
None state.)

Our thread checks if there is a token we can use.  If there isn't, we
set the state to Pending.  If the state was already set to Pending by
some other thread, we block.

```
do mt <- atomically
           (do tokenState <- readTVar var
               case tokenState of
                 None -> do writeTVar var Pending
                            pure Nothing
                 Got t | expired t -> do writeTVar var Pending
                                         pure Nothing
                       | otherwise -> pure (Just t)
                 Pending -> retry)
```

If mt is Nothing it means we decided we need a new token, and made
ourselves responsible for fetching it.  Once we do so we set the state
to Got.

```
   t <- case mt of
          Nothing -> do newToken <- ... fetch new token ...
                        atomically (writeTVar var (Got newToken))
                        pure newToken
          Just existingToken -> pure existingToken

   ... use t ...
```

(Another way to structure such code is to have a transaction return an
IO action which you immediately execute, outside of that transaction.
For example here instead of returning a Maybe from the first
`atomically` block we would return either an action for
renewing the token or an action for doing nothing and using the
existing token.  I don't know if it would make things clearer in
this case but it's worth considering sometimes.)

> Finally, I considered the solution of having a separate thread that is responsible for token renewal.

I think this would also work fine, especially if you are keeping a
token available at all times.  Maybe a little more complicated if you
only want the token to be maintained while threads are using it.

Comment: Can we prevent the program from being left in `Pending` state if the thread that's fetching the token crashes?

Comment: @ollimandoliini the thread could catch its own exceptions, but it looks tricky if you want it to be 100% robust against asynchronous exceptions like being killed by another thread or running out of memory.  Maybe if we record the thread id as part of Pending, an exception handler can identify it and clean up.  But the idea of having a single separate thread to handle the tokens starts to look better, because you just respawn it and it knows it is the only writer.

Comment: This looks interesting! However, in order to test for expiration, the code needs to get the current time, which is an IO operation. If I retrieve the time before entering the `atomically` block, this time could potentially be quite outdated by the time it is compared against the expiration time of the token. I feel like this might not matter in this case, but I would be nice to know how to handle this in general.